# Can a bash script detect if it's **not** being run inside a `systemd` service?

Tags: bash, systemd, shell-scripting, systemd-service

I have a bash script. This script can be started as part of a systemd service (or transient systemd task with `systemd-run`). One can also run it stand alone.

How can I see if “the current script” is being run as part of a systemd service?

I can see if the systemd service is running with `if systemctl -q is-active my_service_name.service ; then …`, but that will always be `true` inside the service. I want to detect if the script is *not* being run as part of that systemd service.

This is run on Ubuntu Linux 18.04, 20.04 & 22.04, so whatever versions of systemd & bash are installed via apt on them.

Comment: You can check the parent process. Variable `PPID` may help

Comment: There are lots of other enviromental things that are easy to detect. perhaps one of them would be easier?

Comment: I assume `run stand alone` means it is invoked interactively from a command line. In that case this should answer the question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46789/check-if-script-is-started-by-cron-rather-than-invoked-manually/46801#46801

Comment: You can add a check for systemd namespace or cgroup